# HTMl anchor link to local file

Tags: html, web-services

I'm testing a locally run web app and am trying to use anchor tags to link to log file output on my C: drive.  The href value that's generated for the anchor is in the standard URI format "file:///C:/outbox/myLog.txt".  But, when I try to click the anchor, the link doesn't go anywhere, I have to right-click and copy the link into the address bar or to a new tab.  I'm not sure why copying the link works whereas the link itself isn't clickable.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the case on different browsers? What is your browser / OS? We've seen this as a fault on Windows XP on both IE and Firefox browsers and may be nothing to do with your code

Comment: My desktop is running Windows 7 Enterprise, I tried it on IE9, Chrome and Firefox and it doesn't work on any of those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you can't link to file:/// from an HTML doc for security reasons. You might want to try [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida).